# Richface picklist values does not populate on right side from database

Tags: richfaces

i am using richfaces 3.3.3. i have made pick list which have selectedvalues coming form database.But its is not showing these values on right side of picklist. here is my code

```
<rich:pickList  sourceListWidth="250" targetListWidth="250"
value="#{users.selectedValues}" >
   <f:selectItems value="#{users.availableValues}" />
</rich:pickList>
```

selected values is a list of object type and available values is list of selectitems.
please can any one help me thanks
regards
Asim satti

Answer (score 3):

```
<rich:pickList value= expression should return List/array you want to get on the RIGHT side (selected items)

<f:selectItems value= expression shall return WHOLE List/array (that is, both selected and unselected items)
```

It works for me